# Can't access a webapp locally

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, web-applications, kubectl, minikube

I am new to Kubernetes, and try to run this simple example:

https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/k8s-in-1-hour

Everything went well, but at the end, when I try to access the webapp locally in browser, nothing is displayed.
This is the status of the minikube components:

```
> kubectl get all 
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mongo-deployment-855b879886-4vh7v   1/1     Running   0          32m
pod/webapp-deployment-9fccd564d-hhvh4   1/1     Running   0          32m

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          33m
service/mongo-service    ClusterIP   10.101.177.31    <none>        27017/TCP        32m
service/webapp-service   NodePort    10.109.199.121   <none>        3000:30100/TCP   32m

NAME                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/mongo-deployment    1/1     1            1           32m
deployment.apps/webapp-deployment   1/1     1            1           32m

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mongo-deployment-855b879886   1         1         1       32m
replicaset.apps/webapp-deployment-9fccd564d   1         1         1       32m
```

and this is the minikube ip:

```
minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

When I connect to http://192.168.49.2:30100 I do not obtain any response.
Is there any way to monitor what is happening on the cluster side when recieving a request?

Comment: It says in the guide as well at the bottom: _If you can't access the NodePort service webapp with MinikubeIP:NodePort, execute the following command:_ `minikube service webapp-service`. Did you try that? :)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. Actually I saw the video, so did not read the whole guide, bad me :(

Comment: I have added it as an answer, feel free to accept/upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it says in the repo shared, you need to run the following command to access it in your browser:

```
minikube service webapp-service
```